# 特定のRakeタスク内でのみ使うメソッドの定義方法

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, rake

Rails内で使うRakeタスクに以下のようなものを使おうとしました。

```
namespace :task1 do
  task :do_something => :environment do
    foo
  end
  def foo
    p "task1"
  end
end

namespace :task2 do
  task :do_something => :environment do
    foo
  end
  def foo
    p "task2"
  end
end
```

`namespace`で区切られているため`foo`メソッドは別のものとして解釈されると思っていたのですがオーバーライドされてしまいました。

特定のRakeタスク内からしか呼び出さないメソッドのスコープを限定するにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

特に決まった方法がないのであれば`task1_foo`などのような命名規則を適用させようと考えています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2011年の記事ですが、こちらに同じような質問が出てますね。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172292/scope-of-rakes-in-a-rails-project

基本的にこの問題を回避する方法はなく、設計で回避するように、みたいなことが書かれています。

rakeタスクはcontrollerのように薄く保ち、ライブラリのメソッドを呼び出すだけの設計にするのが良い、ということみたいです。

Comment: メソッド定義が必要であればモデル側に入れたほうが良いのですね。回答ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

rakeファイル内に定義したメソッドはトップレベルコンテキスト（=selfがmainオブジェクト）で定義されます。

ちょっと格好悪いですが、以下のようにmoduleで包んでincludeしてやれば、当該rakeからしか呼び出せなくなります。

```
namespace :task1 do
  task :do_something => :environment do
    include Task1
    foo
  end
end

module Task1
  def foo
    p "task1"
  end
end
```

その他にも、外部ファイルにメソッドを定義してrequireするなど、やりようはあると思います。少なくとも、プロダクトコードと関係のないメソッドをモデル側に定義するのは、よろしくないと思います。

Answer (score 1):

Refinementsを使うとレキシカルスコープのメソッドを定義できます。

トップレベルのmainオブジェクトの`singleton_class`をrefineする無名モジュールを作り`using`するとそのファイルの中からしか呼び出せないメソッドが定義できます。

Rakeタスクごとにファイルを分割すると、特定のRakeタスクのファイル内でのみ使える同じ名前のメソッドを定義できます。

```ruby
# lib/tasks/task1.rake

top_level = self

using Module.new {
  refine(top_level.singleton_class) do
    def foo
      p "task1"
    end
  end
}

namespace :task1 do
  task :do_something => :environment do
    foo
  end
end
```

```ruby
# lib/tasks/task2.rake

top_level = self

using Module.new {
  refine(top_level.singleton_class) do
    def foo
      p "task2"
    end
  end
}

namespace :task2 do
  task :do_something => :environment do
    foo
  end
end
```

参考: https://qiita.com/hanachin_/items/6cf63dd3987a60e3d264

Answer (score 0):

同じ問題を抱え、 qiita に記事を2つ書きましたが、
http://qiita.com/kuboon/items/26e90800856863c64cdc
http://qiita.com/kuboon/items/dc5f30abee136abcd319
結論としては以下のようにしています。

```
module Anonymous
  namespace :task1 do
    # ここで何を宣言しても安全
  end
end
self.class.send(:remove_const, :Anonymous)
```